# How to get executed Java Child class name from Parent class?

Tags: java, junit

I am executing a Java JUnit test. `Child` test class extends `Parent` test class, and child re-uses naturally `Parent` class `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods. In `Parent` `tearDown()` method I have a method that takes a screenshot of browser window.

I want to name the image by the executing class name. However, I have a problem because I would need to in the `Parent` `tearDown()` get knowledge of the executing `Child` test class name.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@After
public void tearDown() {
  String name = getClass().getName();
  // use name as filename
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `@ClassRule`

create a new class as below

```
import org.junit.rules.TestWatcher;
import org.junit.runner.Description;

public class TestClassName extends TestWatcher{

private String name = null;

protected void starting(Description d){
    name = d.getClassName();
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

}
```

and in your Parent Test case add the following line

```
@ClassRule
public static TestClassName testClassName = new TestClassName();
```

use `testClassName.getName()` in tearDown method